# Calculus - Finding the rate of change of an edge of a cube.

Tags: calculus

A cube is being compacted into a smaller cube. Given that the volume decreases at the rate of change of 4 cubic meters per minute, find the rate of change of an edge of the cube when the volume is exactly 125 cubic meters.

I think I am making this more difficult than what it is...I am used to doing sphere so I am probably missing something simple.

Can someone explain how to set up the problem please?

Comment: It's the same concept- the volumes of spheres and cubes only depend on one measurement- the radius for a sphere and the side length for a cube.

Comment: @Dan Welcome to Maths SE. __2__ things: For questions of this nature it is mandatory that you show some working or at least your thoughts on how to get to the solution, and secondly, if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the known formulae:
\begin{align}
V &= a^3 \\
\frac{dV}{dt} &= 3*a^2*\frac{da}{dt} \\
\end{align}

Since $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is given $\frac{da}{dt}$ can be evaluated knowing edge length at the moment, $a$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the volume of the cube, $V$, is a function of the length of one of the sides ($x$) and time ($t$). Note that $x$ is a function of $t$. We know that
$$V=x^3$$
Therefore, by the chain rule,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
We can then say that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^{-1}$$
You are given $\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$, and $\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}x}$ should be easy enough to calculate.